# Why I'm getting Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module when running the server

Tags: node.js, express, nodemon

I'm doing a startup server. Basically It has initial setup with express and nodemon dependencies. Unfortunately, I'm getting `ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND` when running `yarn dev` or `npm run dev`
Here is the code and file structure I have.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add .js extension
index.js:

```
import { SampleExport } from "../path/file.js"
```

In my opinion, it is better to use .env files together with some npm package or even a json file.

Comment: Thank you, yes, I will use .env but I need env.js for my logic to get prod or dev env. I'm confused why it requires the file extension. I'm currently having react project and importing  just the file name at the end.

Comment: I am glad that my answer will help you, I would be grateful if you would accept it.

Comment: Adding .js to my import worked for me too. Is there a linter that actually warns for that behaviour? @JorgeMontejo

Comment: @MalcolmXYZ I don't know of any extension that would work for you, just keep in mind what CherryDT says, when using import instead of require, you should use the .js extension (unless you are using type script of course).

Answer (score 14):

The issue is a missing file extension. The import needs to look like this:

```js
import { sampleExport } from "../config/env.js";
//                                         ^^^
```

`import` doesn't use the same algorithm that `require` used. Instead, it works according to the ECMAScript Modules specification, which requires a definite extension.

This is also explained in the [node.js docs for ECMAScript modules](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#mandatory-file-extensions):

> A file extension must be provided when using the `import` keyword to resolve relative or absolute specifiers. Directory indexes (e.g. `'./startup/index.js'`) must also be fully specified.
>
> This behavior matches how `import` behaves in browser environments, assuming a typically configured server.

Comment: Thank you.I'm working on react frontend and little knowledge on backend  How it differ from react project when importing? I import as usual without file extension.

Comment: React uses Webpack as bundler configured in such a way that it resolves `import`s in a more relaxed fashion. If you'd use the browsers' native ESM implementation, `import` would also require a file extension.